# PHPUnit-Selenium2: errors when using execute method

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

While generating Acceptance tests using PhpUnit and its Selenium2 extension, I want to use the *execute* method in PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase class to execute Javascript code for checking if the document is ready or not.

If I execute this test:

```
$this->waitUntil(function (LoginTest $driver) {
    if ( $driver->execute( 'return document.readyState;' ) == 'complete' ) {
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}, 10000);
```

I got the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The JSON parameters must be an array, or a NULL value in case they are not required.
```

Then, seeing that it's actually expecting an array, I've tried:

```
$this->waitUntil(function (LoginTest $driver) {
    if ( $driver->execute( ['return document.readyState;'] ) == 'complete' ) {
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}, 10000);
```

Now I'm getting this other error:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
```

How should I call *execute* method?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the test case of *execute* method in https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php#L107, I see that the correct way of calling *execute* is:

```
$this->waitUntil(function (LoginTest $driver) {
    if ( $driver->execute( [
            'script' => 'return document.readyState;',
            'args' => [] 
        ] ) == 'complete' ) {
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}, 3000);
```